# Siebel Open UI and Selenium; changing ID's/names

Tags: java, selenium, siebel

I am working on a project for a client where they are going to upgrade to Siebel Open UI. With that upgrade, they also want to start implementing Selenium. The problem we are currently facing, or going to face once implementing, is that with each build the ID's/Names of HTML elements in Siebel change. Because we are talking about a lot of views and applets it's not a good solution to change the code manually each time.

What is a good solution for this problem? One solution that was offered is a correlation table where we keep track of changes in the ID's.

Xpath in this case is also not a good option because of the complicated structure of the views and applets.

Comment: if its only a id change you should access the elements using xpath

Comment: Yes Xpath is also in option but because of the stucture of the many views and applets this is also not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look into CSS Selectors. They are faster and less brittle than XPath. For ID/names that are dynamic, typically there is at least some portion of the ID that is static.

For instance,

```
<a id="somestatictext_12345">...
```

where "12345" is some dynamically generated number. In this case you can use a CSS selector like

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id^='somestatictext']"));
```

Examples

```
"[id^='somestatictext']" - ID begins with "somestatictext"
"[id$='somestatictext']" - ID ends with "somestatictext"
"[id*='somestatictext']" - ID contains "somestatictext"
```

For more info, take a look at this [CSS Selector reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors).